# Angular 6 RxJS6 observable not returning data in right order

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, rxjs6

I am looping through an array and calling `LoadReportsData`. The `getProjectReportsData` in `_reportingService`  gets called in the correct order. But when the controls returns back from service map is hit and then `.subscribe()` the code inside does not get hit until all the calls are made.

After that, result gets assigned to `this.reportData` but in random order. Due to this behavior my worksheets in the workbook are created randomly and not in intended order. Please suggest if there is a different way to make calls and or suggest some workaround.

```
FetchProjectSubmissionReportingAssets(ID: number,
        mySelectiontot: number, PRsDelimitedList: string, StartDate: string, EndDate: string) {

        let currAsset: string = '';
        let ID: number;
        var fetchAssetData = {
            'CSID': ID
        }
        this._reportingService.isLoading = true;
        this._reportingService.getProjSubRptAssets(fetchAssetData).pipe(
            map(result => {
                if (result != null) {

                    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                        this.ProjReqSubmissionReportingAssets = result;


                        currAsset = result[i].option;
                        ID = result[i].id;

                        this.LoadReportsData(ID, currAsset, i);

                    }
                }
            }))
            .subscribe();


    }


    LoadReportsData(CSAsID: number, currAsset: string, tabIndex: number) {

        this.wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();

            var indata = {
                'CSID': this.CSID,
                'CSAsID': CSAsID,
                'StartDate': this.StartDate,
                'EndDate': this.EndDate,
                'PRsDelimitedList': this.PRsDelimitedList

            }
            this._reportingService.getProjectReportsData(indata).pipe(
                map(result => {

                        this.reportData = result;

                        this.idx = this.idx + 1;

                        if (this.reportData != null) {
                            this.ws = this.ws + '_' + tabIndex.toString();
                            this.ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.reportData);
                            XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(this.wb, this.ws, currAsset);
                            console.log(currAsset);
                        }
                        if (this.ProjReqSubmissionReportingAssets.length == this.idx) {
                            var currDateTime = this.fn_getTimeStamp();
                            XLSX.writeFile(this.wb, "ProjReport_" + this.HCs + "_" + currDateTime + ".xlsx");
                        }

                }))
            .subscribe();

            this._reportingService.isLoading = false;

}
```

Comment: So this method is called in a loop?  It sounds like each iteration may be not be taking the same amount of time, so it's assigned when it's done and not in the order of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making API calls inside a loop, you can make an array of all of them, and `combineLatest` them all. Then the subscriber will eventually receive data in the correct order.

Generally, something like this:

```
    this._reportingService.getProjSubRptAssets(fetchAssetData).pipe(
        filter(result => result !== null),
        map(result => result.map(
            curAsset => this.LoadReportsData(curAsset.id, curAsset, i)
        )),
        switchMap(requestsArray => combineLatest(requestsArray))
    ).subscribe(
        resultArray => {
            // resultArray should consist responses of API calls in the same order
            // the results getProjSubRptAssets(fetchAssetData) came in
        })
```

Comment: mbojko, can you please provide an example?

Comment: Not without the details of that "looping through an array and calling LoadReportsData".

Comment: Updated with calling procedure having loop